# VBA Loop through graphs setting chart type (xlLine), series weight, series colors, chart legend (down), Chart height and width

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts, formatting

I'm constantly experienced bugs when trying to do a makro for formatting my graph. What I want to do is the following: Loop through sheets and graphs setting chart type (xlLine), series weight, series colors, chart legend (down), Chart height and width.

I am trying to utilize the following code:

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    cht.Activate

    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine


  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(214, 198, 138)
    .Weight = 1.5

  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(5, 34, 61)
    .Weight = 1.5
End With

 Next cht
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Currently I get a compile error on "Next cht" in the end of the code and the 1 first line "Sub LoopThroughCharts()" becomes yellow.

Any suggestion for how to overcome this error?

Furthermore it at an earlier state seemed to stop at `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select`

And it seemed to be because some charts only had 1 series. Do you have suggestion to how to overcome this too as at some point I will loop it through another workbook with a many charts with different amount of series.

Just started learning VBA coding.

Comment: You're missing an `End With`. You can use this [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to fix your indentation, and it should be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
  cht.Activate
```

You can work directly with `cht` without activating it.

So for example instead of this:

```
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
  With Selection.Format.Line
```

use this:

```
  With cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line '<< EDIT added Chart
```

Tested:

```
Sub LoopThroughCht()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim co As ChartObject, cht As Chart

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each co In sht.ChartObjects

            Set cht = co.Chart
            cht.ChartType = xlLine

            With cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(214, 198, 138)
                .Weight = 1.5
            End With

            If cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 1 Then
                With cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(5, 34, 61)
                    .Weight = 1.5
                End With
            End If

        Next co
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it dosent seems to remove the error though. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Did you address BigBen's comment?

Comment: Actually i didnt see that comment before, but after doing both your suggestions i still get an error at the fourth last line "Next cht" (Compile error: Next without For)... Furthermore, the seemed to work at first before i added the second seriesCollection.

Comment: I made a typo in my code - see correction above.  It would help to update your post to add your current code though: we can't tell what changes you've made.

Comment: Thanks i just did and also afterwoulds implemented your correction

Comment: Thanks!! That worked like a charm! Tested it with both one and more series. Really, thanks alot! Now i will experience ahead with more formatting.